# Emacs can not activate fcitx

Tags: linux, emacs, slackware

I can use fcitx normally in all of other programs. But I can't not use fcitx in Emacs which means I can not switch to other input method such as Chinese input method. I tried a lot and Googled a lot didn't find solution. This confuses me a lot!

I use `emacs -q` to start emacs.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

1. Emacs version: 25.1.1
2. fcitx version: 4.2.8.5
3. Operating system: Slackware 14.2

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux Planet 4.4.38 #2 SMP Sun Dec 11 16:18:36 CST 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

`fcitx-diagnose` output: [fcitx-diagnose](http://paste.lisp.org/display/339461)

`~/.xprofile` and `~/.profile` both contain the following:

```
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
export LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

Comment: Instead of `fcitx`, you can of course use emacs-specific input methods, including about a dozen choices for Chinese. Press `Ctrl-h` `I` `Tab` for a list.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative solution. But emacs-specific input methods is not as good as fcitx such as fcitx can suggest and remember some words or short sentence. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Googling for `fcitx emacs` also finds [this](https://github.com/cute-jumper/fcitx.el), so I suppose it must work somehow. Maybe contact the author and ask about his setup?

Comment: @dirkt I already this plugin and does not work. I test in other distributions such as Debian and Manjaro with the same settings in `~/.profile` and `~/.xprofile`. Emacs works with Fcitx well. I guess there is something wrong with my Emacs or Fcitx installation. Because in Slackware I have to build them manually. Maybe I miss some build options. But the weird thing is: Sometimes when I reboot or create a new user account on this same operating system, Emacs can activate fcitx, BUT after using them for sometime. Emacs can not activate it. Didn't find the reason right now. :(

Comment: @dirkt Besides, I found a useful Emacs plugin for Chinese input:[https://github.com/tumashu/chinese-pyim](chinese-pyim) yesterday. It works well though not as good as Fcitx. But it is a workaround for me. Again, Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see any description of your problem other than `I can't not use fcitx in Emacs`.  Care to explain in which sense you can't use it?

Comment: @Stefan I use English and Chinese. Those two languages require different input methods. In other applications except Emacs, I can switch between those two input methods of Fcitx. But in Emacs, I can only input English and I can not switch to Chinese input method. This is the problem. I tried to follow the [wiki of fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/FAQ#Emacs) and configure those environment variables as said [here](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables) which don't work.